# Prestashop additional items when selecting products

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am working on a pizza shop on prestashop 1.6. I basically am looking for the functionality that when a customer select any pizza, an option can occur which shows list of available customization of pizza, for example additional cheese, pineapple, egg, etc. Is there any module in prestashop which can handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered implementing them as attributes? Additional products are REALLY hard to implement. There may be a module available though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already did that for different sizes of pizza like small, medium and large. But for additional options I don't see any options there.

Comment: If I were you I'd spend some more time looking for a module. If there isn't one, I'd write my own. You'd probably need to tie extras to the pizza (if the user orders mutiple pizzas), so that mean you'd have to intercept ajax functions and also collect data about ordered products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I solved my problem. The option is under catalog->products->select any product(Edit)->Associations and under that accessories.